# Print Media Footer CSS Not Working With Markdown and markdown-pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, markdown

I am attempting to use the [markdown-pdf](https://github.com/alanshaw/markdown-pdf) node library to generate a pdf document from a markdown document. It is producing the pdf but I cannot seem to get repeating footers working.

The footer is at the end of the document with the following code:

```
<div id="footer">
    &copy; 2013 MyCompany
</div>
```

And the CSS file I am including has the following in it:

```
@media print {
    #footer {
        position: running(footer);
    }
}

#footer {position: relative ; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; font-size:10px; }
```

This produces nicely formatted code on the html page at the bottom left, but the test is not displaying as a page footer on any of the pdf pages.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think there could be 2 problems:

[1] markdown-pdf don't read the element because:

> "A running element is not shown in its natural place; there it is treated as if ‘display: none’ had been set. [...]" -> [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#running-elements0)

[2] markdown-pdf don't read the element because it's only defined for media print. (Maybe markdown read in media screen?)

I hope this thougths could help you.

Possible "solvings":

- try media all/screen
- ask alanshaw if running elements are supported (if not use your relative Css settings)